# Faithul map and (minimal) tensor product of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $f$ be a faithful state on a $C^*$-algebra $A$, i.e. $f(a^*a)=0$ implies $a=0$. in general, call a mapping $T:A \to B$ between $C^*$-algebras faithful if $T(a^*a)=0$ implies $a=0$. How to prove that if $f$ is faithful then the map $f \otimes id: A \otimes A \to A$ is faithful? I think that it should be simple however I don't have an idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See p. 434 in:

> D. Avitzour, [Free products of C*-algebras](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1982-271-02/S0002-9947-1982-0654842-1/S0002-9947-1982-0654842-1.pdf), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **271** (1982), 423–435.

Actually a more general statement holds true; namely tensor products of c.p. faithful maps are faithful.